# catchError not contain all info the error in Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, pipe, try-catch, interceptor

I intercept errors with catchError, **but exists more info about the error in F12 > DevTools > Tab Network > Choose error**, but does not appear in the httpErrorResponse object.

Does the pipe truncate the information?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(httpErrorResponse => {
                console.error(httpErrorResponse);
                return throwError(httpErrorResponse);
            })

        );
    }
```

Comment: can you show what the console.error shows and what the dev tools displays? Also, I recommend adding the type of your `httpErrorRespose: HttpErrorResponse`

Comment: Can you verify the interceptor chain? If there is any other interceptor that is executed before this one which might map the error to a different form.

Comment: I need to capture the error response in an interceptor (Just like you would in the subscribe)